# Unable to install new trezor-bridge on ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, systemd

I would like to install trezor-bridge (2.0.12), however i am unable to proceed. Does anybody know what's the issue please? I am kind of new with linux, would be glad to any answer.

```
root@lubisG2:/home/lubis/Downloads# sudo dpkg -i trezor-bridge_2.0.12_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package trezor-bridge.
(Reading database ... 220309 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack trezor-bridge_2.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking trezor-bridge (2.0.12) ...
Setting up trezor-bridge (2.0.12) ...
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
Failed to issue method call: Unit trezord.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status trezord.service' for details.
dpkg: error processing package trezor-bridge (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 trezor-bridge
```

Comment: What does `journalctl -xe -u trezord` say?

Comment: are you sure this version is supposed to work with 14.04?

Comment: it doesn't say anything:(  just a lot of empty rows..... no i am not sure about that, even though i didn't find anything against...

Comment: From where did you get the Deb package? If it requires systemd it's probably not meant to work with Ubuntu Trusty.